# One function - many buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in HTML a button with id="button1".

We have JavaScript function:

```
$('#button1').click(function() { ... } );
```

It works well.

But what if we have 100 buttons with different IDs?

I can duplicate 100x function. However, this is not very elegant and good solution.

How to easily and effectively solve a problem for many buttons?

The function performed is the same for all buttons.

Comment: You need to use classes, and not IDs as selectors.

Comment: Use a class instead

Comment: Add a class and apply it to all buttons, then listen to clicks on that class

Comment: And some code example like in JS in this case refer to class?

Answer (score 4):

Add a class bind to this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   //dot (.) selector binds to classes
    $('.boundButton').click(function(){ 
         //clicked button
         var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.attr('id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1" class="boundButton">1</button>
<button id="2" class="boundButton">2</button>
<button id="3" class="boundButton">3</button>
```

Comment: And you can even detect which button was clicked by using `this` inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a class instead of ID. For example, your JS code could look like:

```
$('.button-class').click(function() { ... } );
```

and your HTML might look like

```
<button name='example' class='button-class' id='exampleID'>Button Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".btn").on("click", function(){ //attach click event to all buttons with class "btn"
       console.log($(this).attr("id")); //$(this) refers to the button clicked
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn">Button 3</button>
```